# Can't find how to use CompoundEdit

Tags: java, undo, redo

i'm making this application, and i need undo/redo support for the editor. I created a JTextArea and added an UndoManager, just like i saw how to do online somewhere.

But the result is that pressing Ctrl+Z only undoes the last character typed. Again, the character before that, and so on. I would like to group these insignificant edits into a CompoundEdit, as that is what i think it is used for. But i can't find an example anywhere.

How is the correct way to use CompoundEdit for this behaviour to be realized? I'd like a single Ctrl+Z to undo the last word typed, and Ctrl+Y to redo the last word.

Comment: I know this is old, but for anyone who's confused, check out [this article](http://java-sl.com/tip_merge_undo_edits.html).